# CA1001 on autogenerated WPF g.cvb page using Code Analysis

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

After loading a VS2010 project into VS2013 I ran Code Analysis and it threw up 168 warnings for auto-generated g.vb pages (example below)

**CA1001    Types that own disposable fields should be disposable   Implement IDisposable on 'Website_WebPages_Page' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'Service1Client'. If 'Website_WebPages_Page' has previously shipped, adding new members that implement IDisposable to this type is considered a breaking change to existing consumers.  HOA_Manager_Client_04   Website_WebPages_Page.g.vb  41**

Service1Client is a WCF service, and the application does have a memory usage/leak issue still unresolved.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks